# How do you mock classes that are used in a service that you're trying to unit test using JUnit + Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to write a unit test for a service that uses/depends on another class. What i'd like to do is mock the behavior of the dependent *class* (As opposed to an instance of that class). The service method being tested uses the dependent class internally (i.e. an instance of the dependent class isn't passed in to the method call) So for example I have a service method that I want to test:

```
import DependentClass;

public class Service {

    public void method() {
        DependentClass object = new DependentClass();
        object.someMethod();
    }
}
```

And in my unit test of Service method(), I want to mock someMethod() on the DependentClass instance instead of having it use the real one. How do I go about setting that up in the unit test?

All of the examples and tutorials i've seen show mocking object instances that are passed in to the method being tested, but I haven't seen anything showing how to mock a *class* as opposed to an object *instance*.

Is that possible with Mockito (Surely it is)?

Comment: It's definitely possible with [powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

Comment: Also, you may take a look at [partial mocking](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial).

Comment: Yep, It's looking like Powermock is what I need. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy with `Powermockito` framework and `whenNew(...)` method. Example for your test as follows:

```
   @Test
   public void testMethod() throws Exception {
      DependentClass dependentClass = PowerMockito.mock(DependentClass.class);
      PowerMockito.whenNew(DependentClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dependentClass);

      Service service = new Service();
      service.method();
   }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this, and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of poor design. You can always take in the param from a package private constructor.
Your code should be doing something like this:

```
public class Service {

    DependentClass object;
    public Service(){
        this.object = new DependentClass();
    }

    Service(DependentClass object){ // use your mock implentation here. Note this is package private only.
     object = object;
    }

    public void method() {        
        object.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to create a constructor with instances of all the possible classes that the service will use that may need to be mocked. In my case the method under test creates a few instances of the dependent class. I guess what i'd really like to know is if there is a way to inject a mock class when running a unit test.

Comment: You can do that with the help or run time binding but you need to have an service provider implementation. All i was trying to say is that it deviates away from srp. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/should-the-provider-of-an-interface-also-provide-a-mock-implementation-for-testi

Comment: @BrianP, if adding a constructor with all dependencies required is too painful then the code has an design issue and will probably deteriorate more and more. And adding functionality (like business stuff that bring money) will be harder and harder up to outweight the gain of the feature. If that's the case then a refactoring is needed. Use patterns that helps assemble the piece of a software, Observer, Inversion of Dependence, Strategy, etc... On a side note one can alwauys go for the easiest option like Poswermock or partial mock, although they won't help much to craft a good design.

Comment: Agree with @Brice Those option exist for legacy code if you can improve the code then you should do it.

Comment: So if the service being tested, created say 5 instances of the dependent class, you'd have to create the constructor that accepts five instances of that dependent object, right? Think of the dependent class like a general purpose type that's created often ... kind of like you'd create many instances of an integer in a service being tested.

Also, i'll mention that I don't own the dependent class, so I really can't make changes to it.

Comment: You need the constructor of service class not dependent class.