# How do I mock objects in a Java class that has no (non-default) constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, mocking

I am working on setting up the first unit tests for a legacy Tomcat web service that was not written with testing in mind, and doesn't use Spring.  One of the classes I'm having trouble with is a servlet that extends HttpServlet.  Here is an abbreviated version of the class.

```
public class ItemServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private IItemDAO dao;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        dao = new GenericItemDao(...);
    }
}
```

Normally I would pass in the external dependencies to the constructor, but the servlets are created by Tomcat based on the `web.xml` config, which calls only the default constructor and the argument-less `init()` method.  As a result, there doesn't seem to be any way to do dependency injection to allow for my mocks in the unit tests.  The only way I can think of doing this is to create a test-only constructor that I can use to instantiate the class from my unit tests, and leave the init() method the way it is for the actual application to call.  I could also create a third method that could be called by both the constructor and `init()` like so:

```
public class ItemServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private IItemDAO dao;

    public ItemServlet(ObjectMapper mapper, IItemDAO dao) {
        initDependencies(mapper, dao);
    }

    private void initDependencies(ObjectMapper mapper, IItemDAO dao) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        initDependencies(new ObjectMapper(), new GenericItemDAO(...));
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to unit test these classes?

Comment: If you can use [PowerMockito](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) framework, you could mock the constructors of `ObjectMapper` and `ItemDAO` classes. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001713/how-do-you-mock-classes-that-are-used-in-a-service-that-youre-trying-to-unit-te/26054804#26054804). Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the opportunity to decouple the code and make it testable. In fact, if you're instantiating a servlet on behalf of Tomcat, just to check if one of its methods returns an expected value, you're way out of the realm of unit tests and rather are doing integration testing.

Using Mock frameworks to work around this will cast the current implementation in stone and make it impossible to change - unless those changes go along with changes to the tests.

I'm an absolute proponent of unit-testing, and I'm also a pragmatist to do what's possible in case I find myself within several framework layers that make it hard to test. In this case (and I only know of your servlet dependency, not of any other - you'll know where you are) I like to separate my code into

- atomic, unit-testable units with no framework dependencies
- wiring code, that connects the testable code with the frameworks.

The wiring code naturally is not very complex and doesn't get any tests (due to the large number of dependencies). It gets peer-reviewed though.

Comment: I'm not actually testing any servlet functionality, but in fact the business logic within the methods (doPost, doGet, etc.).  You make a good point, however, that if I delegated all of the actual logic to another class (say, ItemRequestHandler), then I could fully unit test that, and leave only the skeleton servlet class untested.  This is exactly the technique I use in another project (NodeJS), and I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You could add `getters`/`setters` to the class and inject the `mocks` into the class through there.